# In which systems are remote procedure calls used in practice?

Tags: rpc

I was just wondering, for what system would we use remote procedure calls if we were building a system

i have an assignment to write about rmc's which i have done but i wanted to give an example along side it, like a real world systrem that isnt already built, like a generic example of when it would be used?

i hope this is a valid programming question?

thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific? What kind of RPC are you referring to?

Answer (score 3):

Windows uses RPC a lot for networking and remote administration. E.g. the "local users and group" mmc snapin uses RPC to communicate with the computer. Thanks to this it is possible to select another computer than the local one to administer.

You can also view web services as remote procedure calls - you call a procedure on a remote host by utilizing SOAP (simple object access protocol) which is an xml message over http.

Comment: It also makes possible for several computers to work on the same task without the end user noticing there are more computers involved than his own.